# How can I plot a function with if statements?

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
def y(x):

    if x <0:
        return np.cos(x)
    else:
        np.exp(-x)

x = np.arange(-2*np.pi,2*np.pi,0.1)      
plt.plot(x,y(x))
plt.show()
```

This function supposed  to plot *y (x)* as *cos (x)* if the *x* value is less than zero, otherwise exp *(-x)*.

I wrote the code, but it gave me an error. How I can fix the error?

I get this error

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. 
Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44345755/5277295

Comment: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are better ways to do this if performance is an issue, but one solution is to serialize your function to apply it to the whole array

```
def y(x):
    if x <0:
        return np.cos(x)
    else:
        return np.exp(-x)

vfunc = np.vectorize(y)
x = np.arange(-2*np.pi,2*np.pi,0.1)      
plt.plot(x,vfunc(x))
plt.show()
```

Probably better in terms of performance:

```
def y(x):
    return np.concatenate((np.cos(x[x<0]), np.exp(-x[x>=0])))

x = np.arange(-2*np.pi,2*np.pi,0.1)      
plt.plot(x,y(x))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Or `np.where(x<0, np.cos(x), np.exp(-x))`

Comment: It's not "better" in the sense that it's probably *slightly* slower, but possibly easier to understand.